# How to store large ever-changing tile map in a database efficiently

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, backend, game-development

I'm currently developing a game as a personal project! One of the main aspects of the game is the map - it will be a multiplayer game whereby players can capture different areas of a map by building things.

The map will be very big! Around 1000x1000 (so 1M tiles). The game will also have a fair amount of players on the map at the same time (100-1000), who will be constantly capturing new areas and stealing areas from other players, as such the tile database will be constantly changing in real time.

My question is - does anyone have any recommendations on how to go about this? My initial ideas were:

**Have a MongoDB database with a collection of tiles.**

Pros: Can query for certain areas of the map so that the client only has to download a portion of the map every time

Cons: Collection will be very large (several GB) (each tile would need to have X, Y coordinates, a resource level, an owner, and whether another player is contesting the tile)

**Have an SQL database**

Pros: Will be lighter in size, probably quicker to query.

Cons: Might not be able to be written to and edited easily in real time.

Any thoughts / direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate your pros and cons are.  For example, regardless of platform, each tile would need to have X, Y coordinates, a resource level, an owner, and whether another player is contesting the tile.  If written well then both platforms should give good performance.  In either case, writing/editing the program might not be 'easy.'

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, It sound like spatial indexing is the way to go. with a good spatial index it will be trivial to locate the player and determine which parts of the map are nearby. I've only ever used it for geo-data, but with the correct polygons it should be usable in your scenario as well.

Microsoft does a much better [explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017) than I can give in a stackoverflow answer, and similar functionality exists in [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Randall! Looks like spatial indexing would definitely help make things easier and quicker on the db

Answer (score 1):

A million tiles is not necessarily a large quantity of objects for a database to manage. Like other types of addressable assets (e.g. airline seats, hotel rooms, concert tickets), each map tile will have a primary key identifier that is indexed for fast retrieval and precise, targeted updates.

Depending on the rules regarding movement across tiles and how much volatile information is involved in rendering a tile, you may want to devise a prefetching scheme that anticipates which tiles a player might need next and downloads them in advance to minimize delays.

In order for your application to accommodate hundreds or thousands of users who are simultaneously viewing, modifying, and taking ownership of specific records without suffering from lock timeouts and deadlocks, your database model and query workload will need to be designed for concurrency. SQL-based databases allow you to use normalization techniques to arrive at a data model which not only accurately represents the data you're managing, but also eliminates the risk of duplicate records, double-booking, lost updates, and other anomalies. If your data model is adequately normalized and your application is making proper use of atomic transactions (units of work), the A.C.I.D. properties of SQL-based databases offer powerful, built-in protection for your data with minimal application coding.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Fred! Very useful info here, will look into atomisation and sql solutions for this